# C# Filter by number

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been trying this for 2 days now and i cant get it to work. I have a datagridview and i wanted to add two filters throught textboxes to it. One for names, and one for numeric code. The one using names works just fine, but i cant get the one for numbers to work, i've tried several pieces of code i found on the internet and none of them worked, you just write a number on the textbox but it wont do the filter on the datagridview!!

Any suggestions? I believe i already tried everything i know and i found on the internet to no avail!

EDIT: This is the piece of code i used for the name filter and tried reusing for the codes:

```
((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "descripcion like'" + busquedanom.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
```

Comment: Is the data you want to filter a number or a string?

Comment: @Ciara The piece of code i put on the post is from the filter by strings, i need that to work with integers but i cant find a way to convert it!

Comment: Its that piece of code, instead of "descripcion like'" i change it for "codSimbolico like'", but codSimbolico is int type, not string!

Comment: If you're dealing with numeric types you'll have to use `=` instead of `like` - if you need the "like" ability you'll have to convert the data into strings.

Comment: @Ciara Tried changing the like for a = , still doesnt work

Comment: @Ciara cant it be a problem between the codes being integer and the input from the textbox a string?

Comment: Should be ok since you are defining the filter in a string anyway, but you might want to replace `busquedanom.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'"` with `busquedanom.Text.Trim()`.

Comment: @Ciara Just tried that, still wont work.

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to chat on my network. Can you post what your updated code now looks like? Maybe you still have the `'` after the equals, if so you need to remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to move this out of the comments...
So, a suggested answer is to replace

```
"descripcion like'" + busquedanom.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
```

with

```
"codSimbolico = " + busquedanom.Text.Trim();
```

Also possibly change `busquedanom` to whatever textbox you are using.

To treat the data as a string instead, try the following:

```
RowFilter = "Convert(codSimbolico, 'System.String') like '" + busquedanom.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
```

Comment: It works partially, upon writing a number on the textbox everything on the datagridview becomes hidden, but when you write the whole code it shows up, while filtering by names, when you write one letter it only hides those names that dont have that one as a first letter, is anyway to do it as a number?

Comment: Yes, this is because of the `=`, I think you would have to convert the data into a string and then use the same logic you have in your name filter. Not sure but you might be able to do it inline in the filter - possibly using something like `tochar(codSimbolico)`.

Comment: looking at the code, it should work, but it didnt and i think i had already tried something like that a few days ago!

Comment: Of course now I left out the single quote I made you get rid of earlier - edited again! Hmm if that still doesn't work I don't know what else you could do besides converting the data itself into string format before putting it in the datagridview... Is it throwing an error or just not working? And if the latter what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: No errors at all, and i had already added the quote just to try it out but didnt work. The behaviour is kind of strange, when you type something on the textbox everything on the grid hides, even if you write the whole code number, if you erase it, still the stuff doesnt come back until i click on the other textbox to filter by name, then the stuff shows again.

Comment: @Lobialkon Ok so I've reproduced this myself and the following is working for me: `((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Convert(Code, 'System.String') like '" + textBox2.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'";` so unless there's something funny with your data I'm all out of ideas :( You might want to update your question to include the work so far and see if anyone else can help.

Comment: i cant thank you enough for your help! surely there was something wrong after so many tries with that textbox so i deleted it and all the events it had and started from scratch, now is working as it should!